# USB-C Wavlink Docking Station

Tags: hdmi, usb-c, docking

After days of unsuccessfully getting nowhere with my Selore USB-C docking station I have changed for a wavlink one which seems to have better reviews.

On first connection, the HDMI ports work straight away. However every so often either one of my screens (not both as same time) go black for a second and then come back.

Where might I start some initial troubleshooting / analysis?

thank you

Comment: Hardware and more specific power consumption. USB-C resets if more power is needed than provided. I see this a lot with upgraded W11 where the system barely manages the new need for power.  You might need one with its own power supply.

Comment: Unfortunately I wish that was the case. The laptop and the docking station both have power plugged in. The docking station via a USBC power adapter (Chicony - rated 45w)

This is less stable than the ancient DELL DisplayLink dock I have used for 2 years.